# Algorithm to enumerate all spanning trees of a graph

Tags: graph

Is there any easy way to enumerate all spanning trees of a indirected graph? This can have O(2^n) complexity. The number of nodes on the graph is always lower than 10. I know Knuth has an algorithm on Volume 4 of TAoCP but I cant find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other works in the literature, did you check them? First an algorithm by Char, which is described in [[Jayakumar et al.'84](http://cs.ou.edu/~thulasi/Algorithm/Complexity%20of%20Computation%20of%20a%20Spanning%20Tree%20Enumeration%20Algorithm.pdf)]. There's also the algorithm of [[Kapoor & Ramesh'91](http://www.hariharan-ramesh.com/papers/spantree1.pdf)], which is described in details in their article, and the work of [[Postnikov'94](http://math.mit.edu/~apost/papers/tree.pdf)]

Also, you might have a look at this other tread: [Find all spanning trees of a directed weighted graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055259/find-all-spanning-trees-of-a-directed-weighted-graph) (some answers mention undirected graphs).

Finally, note that even if the algorithmic complexity is very high, this might not be a problem in practice, on such a small graph.